# Binary expansions of $\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: binary

I was reading *Elements of Set Theory* by Herbert B. Enderton, and I saw there is written:
$$0.1000...=0.0111...=\frac{1}{2}$$

I don't understand how $0.0111...$ is a binary expansion of $\frac{1}{2}$. I'm giving you the text of the book to see if I'm getting it wrong.

[image: Page 149, Academic Press, 2009]

Comment: $0.01111... = \sum_{n\ge 2} 2^{-n} = 2^{-1}$. Maybe the confusion is that this is the binary expansion, not the decimal expansion.

Comment: Take $a_n= 0.0\underbrace{1\cdots 1}_n$ so $a_1 = 0.01, a_2=0.011$ and $b_n=0.\underbrace{0\cdots 0}_n1$ so $b_1 = 0.01, b_2=0.001$ then $a_n+b_n = 0.1$ so letting $n$ go to infinity we have $b_n\to 0$ so we get that $0.0111\cdots = 0.1$

Comment: It is similar to how in decimal notation you have $1/2=0.5000... = 0.49999...$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0.01111\dots$ means the value of the series
$$
\sum_{k=2}^\infty 2^{-k}
$$
Do you know how to evaluate that series?